# A Riemannian manifold with a non-degenerate metric and an inner product $u_{\beta} u^{\beta}=1$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

The question is: given a Riemannian manifold with a non-degenerate metric g and an inner product $u_{\beta}u^{\beta}=1$, is $\nabla_{\mu} (u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0$ without demanding the trivial solution $\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha}=0$? The equivalent question can be raised on a Lorentzian manifold with $u_{\beta}u^{\beta}=-1$. I recently asked this seemingly simple question on Math Exchange but am getting little feedback and would appreciate the expertise on this site.

Given the norm as stated, it is clear that $\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\beta}u^{\beta})=0$ which means $ g^{\alpha\beta}\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0 $. Since g is non-degenerate, $ \mid \nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})\mid=0 $ and $\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0  $ is a  solution (the singular solution of the corresponding  matrix which would be represented by a sum of linear dependent terms) that does not require the trivial solution $\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha}=0  $. The trivial solution is sufficient but not necessary. In fact, $ u_{\beta}\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha}+u_{\alpha}\nabla_{\mu}u_{\beta}=0 $ means $ u^{\beta}\nabla_{\mu}u_{\beta}=0 $ so in general, the vector is orthogonal to the covariant derivative of its covector, and not constant.

The only comment I have had against taking $\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0  $ to be consistent with $u_{\beta}u^{\beta}=1$ and with the vector u being orthogonal to the covariant derivative of its covector, is to require the vector u to be constant. That makes no sense to me. Please give me your valued opinions on this issue.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "an inner product $u_\beta u^\beta=1$. This doesn't characterise the inner product (it characterises $u$).

Comment: Yes It means g(uu)=1.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question. You seem to want to prove two things: 1) $\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0$ and 2) the assumptions are not sufficient to prove $\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha}=0$. For 1), it seems that your second paragraph gives the correct argument. For 2), I think you need to provide a counterexample. I would suggest taking a metric connection $\nabla'$ with nonzero torsion and then choosing $u$ such that $\nabla'u$=0.

Comment: Thank you for your valid comment. I am restricting the connections to those being torsionless. Please note that $\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0  $ is the equivalent of the sum of two orthogonal terms, neither of which can have $\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha}=0 $ for orthogonality to hold; for then, u is just a constant vector. In fact $\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha} $ can be expanded into the vorticity and shear tensors  (GR and the Einstein eqn Choquet-Bruhat (pp409-411). So requiring $\nabla_{\mu}u_{\alpha}=0 $ is definitely not a necessary condition for $\nabla_{\mu}(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=0  $ to hold.

Comment: I meant that the connection with torsion could be used to construct a vector field with constant length but which 'rotates', making it non-parallel for the Levi-Civita connection. There may be simpler ways to construct counterexamples.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.